# Meaning of "for grins"

Tags: phrases

What does *for grins* mean in the following?

> If the web service says the values are valid, the underlying fields
>   are updated. If it says the values are invalid, it sets up error
>   messages for the fields. **For grins**, on an invalid return, it also
>   validates the level number itself.

Comment: Just for the heck of it.. is another way of reading it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"For grins" is typically used as another way of saying "for amusement purposes".

Comment: This is *very* informal usage, BTW.

Comment: I've also seen "for kicks and grins" or "for kicks and giggles."

Comment: There is also "for giggles and sh*ts", and in internet-speak, there is "for LOLs"/"for LOLZ"/"For the lulz" (and other variants).

Comment: @Frustrated: “shits and giggles” is much more common than “giggles and shits”, I think.  Google Ngrams [confirms this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shits+and+giggles%2Cgiggles+and+shits&year_start=1970&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and also suggests that it’s a much more recent coinage than I would have expected.

Comment: @PLL: I agree, the usual order is 'shits and giggles'. I've also heard it as "gits and shiggles". :)

Answer (score 1):

A more common English expression is "for fun." Not for a serious purpose.

Also, "for laughs," or "for kicks."